# how to have fix menu with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/23/

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 110) {
            $('.menu-container').addClass( "fix-menu" ).animate('top', '-3px');

        } else {
            $('.menu-container').removeClass("fix-menu");

        }

    });
```

now when menu get fixed it's not smooth like this : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/4/)

Any idea ? what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to accomplish with transition. This is what the transition css3 animation does: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp

Comment: check the demo link ,menu get fixed with transition , slide out or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/24/

```
.menu-container {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  background:red;
  margin-top:0;
  top:-110px;  /* add this */
}
```

You can add a position to thetop property at the menu-cointeiner and your code works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

may be you will accept this my update:
https://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/37/

What I did:
1. You need to check whether function of animation already ran or not (otherwise on every scroll it will be called). This can be done by checking some outer var for 0 or 1 (it will show whether animation ran or not)
2. I used not "animate" function, but slideDown() - I think it's interesting too, though you can use animate instead, of course.

So here's my updated code:

```
var AlreadyRun=0;  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 110) {
            //$('.menu-container').addClass( "fix-menu" ).animate('top', '-3px');
            if(AlreadyRun == 0){
                AlreadyRun=1;
                //alert('function starts, AlreadyRun='+AlreadyRun);
            $('.menu-container').hide().addClass( "fix-menu" ).slideDown('slow');

            }
        } else {
            AlreadyRun=0;
            $('.menu-container').removeClass("fix-menu");

        }

    });
});
```

and I also think you don't need "transition" in CSS, so I also updated CSS:

```
.menu-container {
   /* transition: all .3s ease-in-out; */
    background:red;
    margin-top:0;
}

.fix-menu{

    /* transition: all .3s ease-in-out;*/
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 54px;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1500;
    /* transition: all 0.2s ease-in; */


}
```

Hope it is what you needed.

Comment: can we have this transition with animation instead of slide down??

Comment: yes, but then it need the CSS update. Take a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/45/

Comment: for some reason I see a wrong link in previous comment, here is correct one: https://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/45/

Comment: another update: as far as .menu-container gets attribute "style" with parameter "top: 0" (after animation this parameter gets "fix-menu", but when it is removed, the "style" inherits the "menu-container". And if this style is not removed, the animation doesn't work if you scroll back and forward. So here is the last update which works: https://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/49/

Comment: I also wrote debug window there, you'll remove it when you don't need it, don't you?..

Answer (score 1):

### CSS transition solution

http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/46/

```js
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 110) {
        if (!fixed)
        {
            fixed = true;
            $('.menu-container').addClass( "fix-menu" );
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        fixed = false;
        $('.menu-container').removeClass("fix-menu");        
    }
});
```

```css
.menu-container {
   transition: top .3s ease-in-out;
    background:red;
    margin-top:0;
    top: -54px;
}

.fix-menu{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 54px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1500;
    top: 0;
}
```

### jQuery animation solution

http://jsfiddle.net/k3AHM/47/

```js
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 110) {
        if (!fixed)
        {
            fixed = true;
            $('.menu-container').addClass( "fix-menu" ).css('top', '-54px').animate({top: '0px'});
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        fixed = false;
        $('.menu-container').removeClass("fix-menu");        
    }
});
```

```css
.menu-container {
    background:red;
    margin-top:0;
}

.fix-menu{
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    height: 54px;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1500;
}
```